# How to reset Backup Password of Authy app

Tags: twilio

The Authy app Backup password not accepting,

and then reset the password link not received on the registered email ID,

anyone please help me how to change Authy app backup password.

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to fix this, earlier I have to install authy app on my Iphone, so again installed Authy Desktop app with the same number then it prompted me to set a Backup password, and after syncing in Iphone also password removed, and I set new backup password which I have set in Desktop authy app.